# Vue : v-for store unmatched items to different container

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for, vuedraggable

I'm trying to build a trello like application
In my case, I have a `user_list` as my categories and `ticket_list` as the items for each categories.
Each item in `ticket_list` holds a corresponding user's id in `user_list` ofcourse. 
Now what I want to do is to have a static `UNASSIGNED` field where I can throw all the items in `ticket_list`that does not have a corresponding `user_id` in the `user_list`.

my code goes like this....

```
<div class="static_ticket_category">
         <span>Unassigned</span>
    </div>
<div v-for="user in user_list" :key="user_index>
    <div class="ticket_category">
        <span>{{user.name}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="ticket_items">
        <div v-for="item in ticket_list">
            <draggable .....>
                <template v-if="item.user_id == user.id">
                    <v-card>
                          ...content goes here
                    </v-card>
                </template>
            </draggable>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above works fine... and of course it does not show all items that doesn't have any corresponding user id.
Now, is it possible to throw all that items that do not belong in any `user_list` categories into the static `Unassigned` category?

Comment: Presumably the ticket_list items have a null or 0 user_id propery if they're unassigned ... ?

Comment: @Andrew, Yes......

Comment: @Lowry answer of computed prop based on the above is where I was going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a good solution to add a computed property which adds the unassigned tickets to an unassigned user and links the tickets with the users in the property.

```
computed: {
    usersWithTicketList () {
        // put users & tickets together in one object
        let users = this.user_list.map(user => {
            let tickets = this.ticket_list.filter(ticket => ticket.user_id === user.id)
            return {...user, tickets}
        })

        // add unnassigned tickets to a fake user
        users.concat({
            id: -1, // fake user id for unnassigned
            // other user info
            tickets: UNNASSIGNED
        })

        return users
    }
}
```

Then your template would look something like this

```
<div v-for="user in usersWithTicketList" :key="user.id">
    <div v-for="item in user.tickets" :key="ticket.id">
        <v-card>
            <!-- we already know this ticket is linked to this user and UNNASSIGNED is in the user list -->
            <!-- thus you don't need a v-if here AND your unnassigned category is taken care of -->
        </vcard>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Imma test it. btw, I'm new to javascript functions like filters. How do I filter it if the ticket_list has a sub-object of array inside it tho... `ticket_list` -> `ticket_list.data` -> `ticket_list.data.ArrayOfObjects`

Comment: `ticket_list.filter(ticket => ticket.data.filter(arrOfObj => arrOfObj.param == someParam).length)` filter just has to return some truthy value. so maybe if you just need to know that a ticket has some param in your array of objects you can return the length of a filter applied to each ticket's arrayOfObject. I hope that made sense. hard to write the answer to that in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a computed property could do the job.

```
<span>Unassigned</span>
<div v-for="n in unassigned_items">{{ n }}</div>
```

And then in the code:

```
computed: {
  unassigned_items: function () {
    return this.ticket_list.filter(function (item) {
         return item.user_id === 0             
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Imma test it. btw, I'm new to javascript functions like filters. How do I filter it if the `ticket_list` has a sub-object of array inside it tho... `ticket_list` -> `ticket_list.data` -> `ticket_list.data.ArrayOfObjects`